# Specify graphite machine to send collectd data to using ip address?

Tags: graphite, collectd

I am trying to configure a CentOS 7 VM to send some performance metrics using collectd to another CentOS 7 VM that is running Graphite so the performance metrics can be displayed graphically.  Below is the configuration parameters for collectd write_graphite in the collectd.conf file:

```
<Plugin write_graphite>
  <Node "commandNode1">
    Host "localhost"
    Port "2003"
    Protocol "tcp"
    LogSendErrors true
    Prefix "collectd."
    # Postfix "collectd"
    StoreRates true
   AlwaysAppendDS false
   EscapeCharacter "_"
  </Node>
</Plugin>
```

Is there anyway that I can specify the host parameter using just the ip address?  Or is there somewhere where I have to associate the IP Address with a given hostname in the collectd.conf file?  For refernce I primarily used this link to get to where I am now: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-keep-effective-historical-logs-with-graphite-carbon-and-collectd-on-centos-7.  Thanks!

Comment: You just need to replace "localhost" with the storage machine backend hostname or IP address, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IP or hostname as long as it resolves to a valid IP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using two different VMs, one with Collectd and the other with Graphite. You need to make sure one VM is able to talk to another VM.

If you are using Virtualbox to bring up these VMs, Virtualbox assigns a NAT'd IP to the VM. The VMs should be able to connect to each other using the NAT IP address, usually its of the form `192.168.x.x`

Use the NAT IP of the VM that's running graphite to configure `write_graphite` plugin, by replacing "localhost" with this IP, in your example of the config above.